# Redis Issue - Incr by to many

Tags: redis

I'm running PHP-FPM with Redis on AWS.

Currently I'm having a really strange issue that I can't seem to figure out.

When I `INCR` or `HINCRBY` and increment by 1 it always increments by around 20 to 30 instead.

I have tried the following:

- Commented out all other redis code (no change).
- Setup a single PHP page using the same code outside of the site (this works fine - increments by 1).
- In the main site (that is having the issue) I put the code in the header, after the last HTML tag and other places and it behaves the same.
- I have an AJAX page within the site which is invoked separately if requested and this works fine. Therefore the issue only occurs during the main site load.
- I've tested redis-cli using the commands and this works fine.

I can't seem to find any loads on the AWS Redis System to read so I'm not sure exactly what is occurring here but it appears the command is running multiple times.

I also read the value back after its written and the value reports correctly. So the increment seems to work - however when I re-check redis using a GUI tool I can see it’s increased by a much larger number.

I'm really at a loss for what to try next and was hoping someone might have some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you invoked MONITOR in redis-cli while loading the page ?

Comment: I have but I'll try that again... what should I be looking for? I guess anything strange.

Comment: I've checked the redis monitor output and I can see it calling the hincrby command multiple times even though it was only executed once... still investigating

Comment: where the php code is? are you sure to execute it only one time? I mean do you call a web page? and is there only one php responding to the call (for example php generated image with an include to this part of the code, or ajax/ws call, etc...)

Comment: Is this a duplicate [of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541484/redis-hincrby-incrementing-by-multiple-numbers)? You’ve made the same mistake here that you made there, i.e. you’ve said “here’s my code” and then not included your code.

Comment: @Adam, have you traced the hash user key to any corresponding code ?